# bytebuddy with aop in springboot not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, byte-buddy

I tried to use bytebuddy to implement aop in springboot. Code as below:

```
package klordy.learning.annotation;
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CostTime {
}
```

```
package klordy.learning.agent;
public class Agent {
private static Agent instance = new Agent();
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Agent.class);
    private Agent() {}
    public static Agent getInstance(){ return instance; }
    public void install() {
        ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        AgentBuilder.Listener listener = new AgentBuilder.Listener() {
            // do nothing
            ...
        };

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("klordy.learning"))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                        builder.visit(Advice.to(TimeAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(named("klordy.learning.annotation.CostTime")))))
                .with(listener)
                // *** added as supposed, but still seems not work.
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .installOnByteBuddyAgent();
         logger.info("byte buddy modification done.");
     }
}
```

```
public class TimeAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static long enter(@Advice.AllArguments Object args[], @Advice.Origin Method method){
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    static void exit(@Advice.Enter long startTime,
                     @Advice.Return(typing = Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC) Object result,
                     @Advice.Origin Method method,
                     @Advice.Thrown Throwable throwable){
        if(throwable != null){
            System.out.println("error func " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }else {
            System.out.println("func takes " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Listener of springboot as below:

```
public class AppEnvListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppEnvListener.class);
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent applicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
        Agent.getInstance().install();
        logger.info("finished byte buddy installation.");
    }
}
```

At last, register listener in springboot startup:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "klordy.learning")
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(SpringBootDemoApplication.class);
       // register listener
       application.addListeners(new AppEnvListener());
       application.run(args);
    }
}
```

As I start up the application, debug logger showed fine. However, the aop does not work when request is processed. What am I doing wrong? I am confused...

Comment: As usual, Rafael's answer concerning BB is correct. Just out of curiosity: Why are you using BB when in Spring Boot you already have two full-fledged AOP frameworks (Spring AOP and AspectJ) at your disposal?

Comment: Interested and new coming in BB.Just for learning. @kriegaex

Comment: If you want to concentrate on learning BB, maybe start in simpler Java SE environment, try with and without Java agent and get to know the API before switching to a container or application server environment so as to reduce the number of variables or "moving parts" in your system. 

Comment:  Thanks for advice, I‘ll take it and try to learn more about the APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I found your problem by recreating your situation with Spring Boot. It would happen without Spring too, though. Basically you hit [this problem](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/123#issuecomment-216822493).

So if you modify your advice to `@Advice.OnMethodExit(onThrowable = Throwable.class)`, you should be fine. You also should add `.disableClassFormatChanges()` to your agent, BTW. It helps avoid problems retransforming previously loaded classes. The JVM requires them not to be changed structurally.

How did I find out what was happening? I activated console logging in ByteBuddy. Previously I had used your listener, making it log every action, so I could see that BB in fact was getting triggered. But BB logging really showed the exceptions due to your wrong usage of `@Advice.Thrown` (without `onThrowable = Throwable.class` in the advice annotation).

```java
public void install() {
  ByteBuddyAgent.install();
  new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .disableClassFormatChanges()
    .with(RETRANSFORMATION)
    .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
    .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withTransformationsOnly())
    .with(AgentBuilder.InstallationListener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
    .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("klordy.learning"))
    .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
      builder.visit(
        Advice
          .to(TimeAdvice.class)
          .on(isAnnotatedWith(named("klordy.learning.annotation.CostTime")))
      )
    )
    .installOnByteBuddyAgent();
  logger.info("byte buddy modification done.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class in question is likely already loaded.

Set `.with(RetransformationStrategy.RETRANSFORM)` in your agent configuration or install your agent before loading Spring in your `main` method.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried to set `.with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)` in the agent configuration, but still not work.